# Textbox class changes size / pos when giving it a class

Tags: python, tkinter

Using tkinter, I have a class which when I refer to a text input box completely messes up the placement / size

Before: [This shows what it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASEvq.png)

Code:

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import * 

class ModifiedMixin:
    '''
    Class to allow a Tkinter Text widget to notice when it's modified.

    To use this mixin, subclass from Tkinter.Text and the mixin, then write
    an __init__() method for the new class that calls _init().

    Then override the beenModified() method to implement the behavior that
    you want to happen when the Text is modified.
    '''

    def _init(self):
        '''
        Prepare the Text for modification notification.
        '''

        # Clear the modified flag, as a side effect this also gives the
        # instance a _resetting_modified_flag attribute.
        self.clearModifiedFlag()

        # Bind the <<Modified>> virtual event to the internal callback.
        self.bind_all('<<Modified>>', self._beenModified)

    def _beenModified(self, event=None):
        '''
        Call the user callback. Clear the Tk 'modified' variable of the Text.
        '''

        # If this is being called recursively as a result of the call to
        # clearModifiedFlag() immediately below, then we do nothing.
        if self._resetting_modified_flag: return

        # Clear the Tk 'modified' variable.
        self.clearModifiedFlag()

        # Call the user-defined callback.
        self.beenModified(event)

    def beenModified(self, event=None):
        '''
        Override this method in your class to do what you want when the Text
        is modified.
        '''
        pass

    def clearModifiedFlag(self):
        '''
        Clear the Tk 'modified' variable of the Text.

        Uses the _resetting_modified_flag attribute as a sentinel against
        triggering _beenModified() recursively when setting 'modified' to 0.
        '''

        # Set the sentinel.
        self._resetting_modified_flag = True

        try:

            # Set 'modified' to 0.  This will also trigger the <<Modified>>
            # virtual event which is why we need the sentinel.
            self.tk.call(self._w, 'edit', 'modified', 0)

        finally:
            # Clean the sentinel.
            self._resetting_modified_flag = False
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from tkinter import Text, BOTH

    class TextInput(ModifiedMixin, Text):
        '''
        Subclass both ModifiedMixin and Tkinter.Text.
        '''

        def __init__(self, *a, **b):

            # Create self as a Text.
            Text.__init__(self, *a, **b)

            # Initialize the ModifiedMixin.
            self._init()

        def beenModified(self, event=None):
            '''
            Override this method do do work when the Text is modified.
            '''
            print(self.get("1.0","end-1c"))


root = Tk()

# This is the section of code which creates the main window
root.geometry('189x62')
root.configure(background='#F0F8FF')
root.title('Test')


# This is the section of code which creates a text input box
tInput=Entry(root)
tInput.place(x=25, y=20)


## Opening and saving ##

with open("YES.txt") as f:
    all_names = f.readlines()

all_names = [x.strip() for x in all_names] 

## Searching ##

def searching():

    search_term = getInputBoxValue()

    print (search_term)

    found_names = filter(lambda name: search_term in name, all_names)

    results = list(found_names)

    print (results)

    if search_term == "break":
        pass

    else:
        pass

root.mainloop()
```

After giving class: [This shows what happens when I add it, also same thing when I drag it to make it bigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kBCd.png)

After Code:

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import * 

class ModifiedMixin:
    '''
    Class to allow a Tkinter Text widget to notice when it's modified.

    To use this mixin, subclass from Tkinter.Text and the mixin, then write
    an __init__() method for the new class that calls _init().

    Then override the beenModified() method to implement the behavior that
    you want to happen when the Text is modified.
    '''

    def _init(self):
        '''
        Prepare the Text for modification notification.
        '''

        # Clear the modified flag, as a side effect this also gives the
        # instance a _resetting_modified_flag attribute.
        self.clearModifiedFlag()

        # Bind the <<Modified>> virtual event to the internal callback.
        self.bind_all('<<Modified>>', self._beenModified)

    def _beenModified(self, event=None):
        '''
        Call the user callback. Clear the Tk 'modified' variable of the Text.
        '''

        # If this is being called recursively as a result of the call to
        # clearModifiedFlag() immediately below, then we do nothing.
        if self._resetting_modified_flag: return

        # Clear the Tk 'modified' variable.
        self.clearModifiedFlag()

        # Call the user-defined callback.
        self.beenModified(event)

    def beenModified(self, event=None):
        '''
        Override this method in your class to do what you want when the Text
        is modified.
        '''
        pass

    def clearModifiedFlag(self):
        '''
        Clear the Tk 'modified' variable of the Text.

        Uses the _resetting_modified_flag attribute as a sentinel against
        triggering _beenModified() recursively when setting 'modified' to 0.
        '''

        # Set the sentinel.
        self._resetting_modified_flag = True

        try:

            # Set 'modified' to 0.  This will also trigger the <<Modified>>
            # virtual event which is why we need the sentinel.
            self.tk.call(self._w, 'edit', 'modified', 0)

        finally:
            # Clean the sentinel.
            self._resetting_modified_flag = False
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from tkinter import Text, BOTH

    class TextInput(ModifiedMixin, Text):
        '''
        Subclass both ModifiedMixin and Tkinter.Text.
        '''

        def __init__(self, *a, **b):

            # Create self as a Text.
            Text.__init__(self, *a, **b)

            # Initialize the ModifiedMixin.
            self._init()

        def beenModified(self, event=None):
            '''
            Override this method do do work when the Text is modified.
            '''
            print(self.get("1.0","end-1c"))


root = Tk()

# This is the section of code which creates the main window
root.geometry('189x62')
root.configure(background='#F0F8FF')
root.title('Test')


# This is the section of code which creates a text input box
tInput=TextInput()
tInput.place(x=25, y=20)

## Opening and saving ##

with open("YES.txt") as f:
    all_names = f.readlines()

all_names = [x.strip() for x in all_names] 

## Searching ##

def searching():

    search_term = getInputBoxValue()

    print (search_term)

    found_names = filter(lambda name: search_term in name, all_names)

    results = list(found_names)

    print (results)

    if search_term == "break":
        pass

    else:
        pass

root.mainloop()
```

So you see the text input box in the top picture is in the middle. When I give it a class though it moves to the bottom side and stays their. I want it to keep the same placement when given the class

(Sorry if this isn't formatted well, this is my first question on here.)

(Edit, Sorry let me post the full code.)

Comment: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Your first block of code uses an `Entry`, your second uses a `Text` - those are profoundly different types of widgets!

Comment: Mk, the function seems to work tho both times. Just the placement.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I have fixed it. What I had to do was to put these 2 lines into the class function:

self.configure(width=20, height=1)
self.place(x=19, y=247)

Cheers!